# Trying out Geb in the Groovy Console

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, geb

I am trying to do some really simple bare bones inline coding with Geb in the Groovy Console.

I installed Groovy, downloaded the Geb jar and have Selenium downloaded.

I have opened the console and pasted in the very simple :-

```
@Grapes([
@Grab("org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2"),
@Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.28.0"),
@Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.28.0")
])

import geb.Browser

Browser.drive {
 go "http://google.com/"
 assert title == "Google"
}
```

When I run this, Firefox opens and hangs on a blank page for ages before the console responds with a spam of errors that is too long to post here.

So I put it on PasteBucket
Link  ->   http://www.pastebucket.com/40187

I am really struglging to just get started with Geb. I had no problems taking off with Selenium Webdriver and doing automation via Java scripts, but after a few hours of struggling through vague or overly complex guides I am still unable to make even the simplest Geb script run.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I have missed some important steps.

Comment: I am having this problem on Windows with Geb 0.10.  I've submitted a lengthy edit describing the problem in more details and adding more comments.

Comment: Let me also note that the script I posted works just fine from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

On line 162 in the error link I can see:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on **port 7055**; process output follows:

I have tried the example in the Eclipse with dependencies as listed [here](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/intro.html#installation__usage) (selenium jars version 2.43.1) and got [similar error](http://goo.gl/0kCMjn):

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Then I have switched to latest jars version 2.46.0 as per [Webdriver Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms) and it worked just fine. My Firefox version is 38.0.5 (latest in the moment)

---

Why doesn't it work with the old version? A tcp connection was half open

> TCP    127.0.0.1:57855        127.0.0.1:7055         SYN_SENT        6760

and thread dump showed that main thread tries to read from the socket:

> Thread 1: (state = IN_NATIVE)
>   -java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(int, java.net.InetAddress, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
>   -java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(java.net.InetAddress, int, int) @bci=28, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
>   ......................................................
>   -org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) @bci=7, line=120 (Interpreted frame)
>   -org.toni.geb_test_jar.GebTestSimple.main(java.lang.String[]) @bci=13 (Interpreted frame)

which makes me think the part of the driver which runs in Firefox was hanging for some reason.

Comment: Works for me through groovyConsole. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You didn't really ask a question... but your implied question is: "How do I get started with Geb?"

I have an [example Geb project on GitHub](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/geb-examples) and a few screencasts on how to get started with Geb on my blog:

- [Geb Automation Quick Start](http://qualityshepherd.com/2014/03/screencast-geb-automation-quick-start/) (Geb basics)
- [Geb Examples Project Overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ufBPYXYXDg) (runs you through my example project)
- [Creating Your First Test In Geb](http://qualityshepherd.com/2014/03/screencast-creating-your-first-test-in-geb/)

Comment: Let me disagree with you. The question is about why it doesn't works as written in tutorial. But you provide a few more 'getting started'.