# org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Tags: json, selenium

Code use:

```
enter code here
       ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("Other");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
        driver.get("http://google.com");
```

:Run the source the Firefox page open but google.com not opening error

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
reg-app-global","addons":{"fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Fiddler2\\FiddlerHook","mtime":1409222185915,"rdfTime":1406724252000}}},{"name":"app-global","addons":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","mtime":1411627483703,"rdfTime":1411627483531}}},{"name":"app-profile","addons":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Users\\RT-13\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous3444483664614526613webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","mtime":1411630550698,"rdfTime":1411630550495}}}]
1411630550942   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database C:\Users\RT-13\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous3444483664614526613enter code herewebdriver-profile\extensions.json
1411630550943   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: block`enter code here`list is disabled
1411630551091   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1411630551094   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1411630551095   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1411630551095   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1411630551098   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1411630551098   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1411630551098   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1411630551098   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com installed in winreg-app-global
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms)

Answer (score 2):

Please downgrade the `Firefox version` to **31** and add the latest `selenium standalone server 2.43` library into the build path. This is a common issue that every one face at least once in a week:)

Answer (score -1):

## Solution -

1) Upgrade your Selenium Server i.e. selenium jar "selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.x.JAR" TO **"selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.JAR"**

2) Upgrade your Selenium Client Driver i.e. selenium libs folder "selenium-java-2.xx.x" TO **"selenium-java-2.45.0"**

3) Check and Install compatible version of Firefox

This will RESOLVE your problem.. Cheers !!

Refer - [Download updated selenium libs & jar i.e. Version 2.45.0](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/)

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. If they are duplicates, then use your flags to flag them as duplicates. If they are not duplicates, then you need to adjust your answer to that exact question. I understand that you cannot currently flag questions as duplicates, but posting duplicate answers is not the way to go.