# Im getting an error when trying to run a cucumber test, which manipulates a confirm dialogue using selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I just want to get my cucumber test to accept a confirm dialogue, with my cucumber test, I've installed selenium-webdriver and it gives me this error:

unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

I tried running gem update selenium-webdriver, and that didn't work.

Here is my the feature file:

Feature: Delete User
    In order to remove an exisiting user
    As a user
    I want to be able to remove a user from the database

```
Scenario: User successfully deletes another user
    Given I am currently on the Users page
    When I select a user to delete
    Then the user should no longer visible on the users page
```

Here is relevant part of the steps file:

## Feature: Delete User, Scenario: User successfully deletes another user

When /^I select a user to delete js: true$/ do
    page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
    find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/users/2?page=1' and @data-confirm='Are you sure?']").click
end

Then /^the user should no longer visible on the users page$/ do
    expect(page).to have_no_content "cwl0@aber.ac.uk" 
end

Here is the env.rb file:

require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Dir["../../spec/factories/*.rb"].each {|file| require_relative file }

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

## Remove/comment out the lines below if your app doesn't have a database.

## For some databases (like MongoDB and CouchDB) you may need to use :truncation instead.

begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

Before do
DatabaseCleaner.start
load Rails.root.join('db/seeds.rb')
end

After do |scenario|
DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation

And here is the gemfile:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'thin'

gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'

gem 'simple-navigation'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'

## Required by Windows and some Linux platforms when running with Rails 4.1.5!

gem 'tzinfo-data'

## Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'

gem 'rails', '4.1.5'

## Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

gem 'sqlite3'

## Use SCSS for stylesheets

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

## Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

## Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'oauth', '~>0.4.6'

## See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes

## gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

## Use jquery as the JavaScript library

gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.3.0"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '4.1.2'

## Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

gem 'turbolinks'

## Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', "~> 2.38.0"
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

Please can someone suggest the best way of testing this feature, which allows me to accept the confirm dialogue?

Comment: What version of firefox are you using?  I would get the lastest version of FF and download newest selenium drivers.  More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms

Comment: Just tried to update to the latest selenium driver with bundle update, and its giving me another error now, what a nightmare: An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.6'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: ok managed to fix the ffi problem (hopefully), updated latest version of firefox and selenium, still getting the same problem. I'm not sure if I need to explicitly state that the tests should use selenium, or if I need to include something in the tests that use it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I think you need to install selenium-client.

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Setting-up-Selenium

Comment: Just installed selenium-client, that doesn't work either. I also tried to use capybara-webkit today, but that gave me a different error which also seemed unsolveable, it was trying to connect to the users page using https and failed

Comment: What version of JRE are you running?

Comment: Also is there a reason you are using version 2.38 of selenium-webdriver?  The latest version is 2.44

Comment: java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)

Comment: I had specified version 2.38 of selenium-webdriver to try and fix the problem, as per a suggestion I found online, this didn't work, so I now have the latest version installed again

Comment: When I tried with capybara-webkit it seemed to fail due to being unable to open the users page via https. To get the other tests which just use capybara running I have had to comment out a couple of lines to do with ssl: force_ssl except: [:destroy] (in sessions_controller), and: return unless config.use_ssl (in force_ssl_extension, under config/initializers). I wonder if the error with capybara-webkit is due to the ssl configuration and the fact that it doesn't work with https, but I'm not sure how to get it working with https even if that is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version of selenium-webdriver that you are using compared to your version of Firefox for compatibility and make the appropriate version change in your gemfile.lock file. https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES

Older Firefox versions can be found here
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

Comment: Thanks for this, I managed to get it partly working by rolling back to Firefox 25, but it still doesn't work properly. It manages to log a user in, but doesn't get any further than that in the javascript test, when it supposed to open the users page after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile have the following:

```
group :test do
  gem "capybara"

  # selenium webdriver is a dependency of Capybara. However it needs updating
  # much more frequently to keep up with firefox. Including it in the Gemfile
  # allows us to run 'bundle update selenium-webdriver' when this happens.
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

Then follow the instructions in the comment i.e. run

```
bundle update selenium-webdriver
```