# After Launching browser in selenium webdriver using java and windows not passing URL and it does not open url

Tags: selenium-webdriver

After Launching browser in `selenium` web driver using Java and windows not passing URL in web address and it does not open URL.

Thanks

Comment: what code you have tried? What error you getting? Which browser you are using??

Comment: WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");                                                               it does not open google alreday i have updated jar file as well Firefoxbrowser but getting same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give protocol `http` in `driver.get()` as

`driver.get("http://google.co.in");`

If not will throw `webDriverException`

Comment: Already i have applied protocol but getting error unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. firefox console output                          and i have also checked with latest version selenium webdriver and latest version of filefox but getting same error.

Comment: Please check if the port 7055 is free if running in background

Answer (score 0):

`driver.get("google.co.in");` will not work.

You should specify the protocol that you will be using like http or https.

Use `driver.get("http://google.co.in");`

Comment: Already i have applied protocol but getting error unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. firefox console output                          and i have also checked with latest version selenium webdriver and latest version of filefox but getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the compatibility of Firefox version and Selenium version.

Try out Firefox 30 with Selenium 2.45 and use

driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");

It will work.

Comment: this has been giving me hell for a full day now. i have tried installing older versions,and also tried Firefox 30 with Selenium 2.45 but stilll getting same issues i cant escape this error! help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Error log:-Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
1428561678308 addons.manager DEBUG Application has been upgraded
1428561678317 addons.manager DEBUG Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1428561678319 addons.manager DEBUG Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1428561678321 addons.xpi DEBUG startup

Comment: could post the code that you have used to create the firefox driver?

Comment: driver=new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=dmIiVZekCsqDuASWqYHgCA&gws_rd=ssl");
   driver.close();

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the same error reported earlier in stackoverflow
[Webdriver Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms)

hope this helps.

Is firefox browser launching? which OS are you using. Also please refer to my earlier answer, did you try

```
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
```

Comment: Which is the firefox version you are using?

Comment: currently i am using FF31 and Latest selenium .