# Not able to run ant script from jenkins in Cent OS 7

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins, ant, centos

```
   [testng] [TestNG] Running:
   [testng]   suite1
   [testng] 
   [testng] 
   [testng] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
   [testng] Error: no display specified
   [testng] Error: no display specified
   [testng] 
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] suite1
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
   [testng]     at test.webdriver.browser.FireFoxBrowser.invoke(FireFoxBrowser.java:20)
   [testng]     at test.webdriver.SonnetElementBase.invokeBrowser(SonnetElementBase.java:125)
   [testng] Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
   [testng]     at scripts.RedBus.setup(RedBus.java:26)
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng]     at scripts.Driver.signup(Driver.java:44)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   [testng]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
   [testng] 
   [testng] The tests failed.`enter code here`
```

I was able to run the selenium scripts using ant(build.xml) from command line and invoke the firefox browser.When i run the same build.xml from the jenkins i am the getting the above mentioned error.Please let me know what might the issue.I am using the Cent OS 7

Comment: Probably duplicated with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms