# Unable to go for next Annotation of selenium browser automation with simple java codes

Tags: java, selenium

The thing what I wanted to do was automate the Firefox browser for search an item in the search bar. My java codes are as follows.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FlipkartTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CharSequence[] cs = {"Dell"};
        //CharSequence[] d = String[]{"Dell"};
        //String s = toString();        

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("fk-top-search-box")).sendKeys(cs);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=Search]")).click();
    }
}
```

After debug or run the code a new Firefox window is appeared, But when click on next Annotation button, Nothing was happened. it doesn't go for next step such as opens the Flipcart.com site or searches the word.

After run the code, The console display a list. I found this line from it.

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
```

So how I fix this problem?

Comment: can u tell us what are u trying exactly so that we would understand it better

Comment: I wanted to Automate the browser with selenium web driver. I write that codes by looking at a tutorial. first it opens the Firefox, then go to flipkart.com. type a string in the search bar and submit. But after run the code, it opens the firefox browser only.

Comment: well the code here does the same thing and it works well for me https://github.com/mrunalgosar/cucumber-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/flipkart/FlipkartImpl.java

Comment: In my peace of codes, nothing error is showing. but it does not continue next steps. Can be any other reason for that.

Comment: try to run your code in debug mode and see which  line is problematic

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms)

Comment: @guy , I got the point from your link. It is 3 rd answer of it. The problem is about selenium standalone server version. I have added the version 2.44 of selenium. Then I added latest version 2.48 which compatible with Firefox 43.0.3. If you can give it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms) the problem is in mismatch between `selenium` and `Firefox`. Updating them to the latest version should solve the problem.

Comment: I got the point from your link. It is 3 rd answer of it. The problem is about selenium standalone server version. I have added the version 2.44 of selenium. Then I added latest version 2.48 which compatible with Firefox 43.0.3. If you can edit this answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to first set the properties of the Firefox driver and then create an instance of it. Something like this -

```
Webdriver driver=null;
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver"."//your firefox driver path");
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

Also try with ChromeDriver and InternetExplorerDriver and check if the problem still persists.