# I am using firefox 43.0.4 and Selenium java version 2.49.0. Error description below

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms)

Comment: try to downgrade to selenium 2.48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of the release cadences of both Firefox and Selenium Webdriver. When Firefox release a new version, it generally isn't supported by Selenium vlatest. My recommendation from experience is:

- Disable Firefox Automatic Updates (Options->Advanced->Update)
- Manually keep Firefox as up-to-date as possible without breaking Selenium Compatibility (unfortunately as far as I know, there isn't a definitive compatibility matrix)
- Always try and keep Selenium up-to-date

This is particularly important for any Selenium boxes used as part of a CI/CD pipeline, which will otherwise auto update and fail.

For downgrading Firefox, Mozilla provide a directory of older versions:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/