# cron jobs - Selenium - org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cron, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using the following:

```
Maven 3.1
Selenide v3.5
Selenium v2.53
Firefox v45.0.1
Linux aws
```

when I run all test shell script, all running were successfully completed **without occurring Not Connected Exception**.

But when I make a cron jobs to repeat running this shell, I got this exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
```

I search for this issue and some consider the problem due to use cron jobs, as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms).

[image]

> So how to deal with this issue? I have to use a cron jobs and in the same time I need to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using cron job, it seems that you want to trigger tests at particular time of the day or on a particular day. If this is your goal then you can accomplish this by Jenkins as well. Jenkins is free, easy manage, it can trigger build at the time you want. check details here - 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/index.htm