# WebDriverError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

> Selenium not starting when i run protractor tests in firefox. The
>   dependency version details are specified as below:
>
> Let me know what is going wrong and what am i missing?

Node Version: `v4.3.1`

Protractor Version: `3.2.1` Karma version: `0.13.21`

Selenium version: `2.52.0`
Firefox version: `47.0.1`

---

**Firefox console output:**

```
C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27
    super(opt_error);
         ^
WebDriverError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
MlocE","location":"winreg-app-global","version":"15.1.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://vscore/content/ScriptFF.gif","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"McAfee ScriptScan for Firefox","description":null,"creator":"McAfee, Inc.","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":true,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore","installDate":1465363824840,"updateDate":1465363824840,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":2695168,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"1.5","m
1467645009572   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1467645009572   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1467645009572   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1467645009579   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1467645009586   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1467645009587   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1467645009587   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1467645009588   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1467645009589   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1467645009590   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1467645009609   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1467645009609   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1467645009610   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1467645009610   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1467645009610   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1467645009610   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1467645009616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1467645009617   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1467645009617   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1467645009617   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1467645009617   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1467645009618   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1467645009955   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1467645009955   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1467645009955   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1467645010210   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1467645010210   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1467645010210   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1467645010247   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1467645010259   addons.repository       DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1467645010260   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Save changes
1467645010263   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting timer
1467645010426   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1467645010426   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1467645010426   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1467645010431   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting write
1467645010455   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1467645010505   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27:10)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:580:13)
    at C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:64:13
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
    at C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27
    at C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at acquireSession (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:62:22)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:295:12)
    at Builder.build (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:458:24)
    at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:42:27)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:203:37)
    at C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:293:21
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\tester\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms

Comment: there are so many similar questions in stackoverflow and the one you are  referring is 3 years old question that would not solve the current version problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Comment: @Hansie meant be duplicate of what alessandro is specified!!

Comment: I'll still keep the answer since it is protractor specific and has some additional information about the problem. Hope it'll help others with similar protractor+firefox issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox 47 has [*compatibility issues*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47) with the selenium webdriver 2.53 (you have 2.52, but I think it is still a problem). You need to either [downgrade Firefox to 46.0.1](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/) or install the *latest development version* of Firefox which contains the fix.

Or/and, you should *upgrade Protractor* to the latest (3.3.0 at the moment), which will bring the latest `selenium-webdriver` package with itself (note: Protractor tries to sync with the latest updates in `selenium-webdriver`, but 3.3.0 specifically [depends on the same 2.52.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3.3.0/config.json#L3), while there is 2.53.2 out there - the next 3.4.0 [will have that installed](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3223)).

Comment: Firefox 47 is the latest version as of now. So do you want me to try upgrading protractor or downgrade Firefox? Chrome has no issues FYI

Comment: Firefox 47.0.1 already has the fix. Alex is right - latest selenium 2.53.1 should be used with latest firefox, but protractor dependency isn't updated yet.