# Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 28

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am getting error while using Firefox with webdriver.

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
```

Firefox version:28.0
Selenium-Java-2.37.0
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0
Windows 7 / 64 bit

Is anyone getting a similar issue or any idea what is the solution for this. It's working fine with Chrome but with Firefox none of the URLs are getting loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs when selenium is not compatible with your version of Firefox. Try to downgrade selenium or upgrade Firefox. See this question on SO [Webdriver Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms)