# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 error

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, firefox

I'm getting the error:
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055

when I try to run selenium with firefox on an ubuntu server.

can anyone please help?

I have selenium version 2.53

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588082/webdriver-unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055-after-45000-ms)

Comment: Have a look  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium..

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because you are using incompatible version of firefox for Selenium version 2.53. The selenium version you are using only supports Firefox until 2.45. Please see change logs [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG). Downgrade your firefox to 2.45 or below and rerun

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to Selenium 2.53.1 and Firefox 47.0.1. It can fix your problems.